# How can I make an inward rounded corned on only 1 corner? I have two rectangles on my screen and I want them to have a corner as shown in the picture

Tags: react-native

[image]
Trying to make rounded corner go inward to create a semi-circle illusion on the rectangular shape.

```
leftContainer: {
    width:'50%',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    flex: 1,
},
rightContainer: {
    width:'50%',
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    flex: 1,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with 3rd View. Position it absolute and give it border radius of '50%'.

Comment: I’m sorry, what is 3rd view?